# Проверка на работу сайта PHP

Tags: php

Хочу проверять свои сайты с админ сайта на работу. Как это лучше организовать? Думаю сделать специальные ссылки для каждого и получать с них ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать проверку кода ответа сервера, где расположен сайт.
Это легко делается с помощью cURL.

```
$checkURL = "http://vozhzhaev.ru"; // Домен для проверки

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $checkURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // Получаем HTTP-код
curl_close($ch);
echo $http_code; //Выводим на экран код ответа
```

В переменной `$http_code` будет код ответа от сервера. В данном примере `$checkURL` указан рабочий сайт, поэтому ответ приходит 200.

[Клиентская библиотека работы с URL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

[Список кодов состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

Вы так же можете использовать для этой цели функцию `get_headers()`:

```php
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$code = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
switch ($code) {
    case 200:
        echo 'OK';
        break;
    case 403:
        echo 'Forbidden';
        break;
    case 404:
        echo 'Not Found';
        break;
}
```

Данная функция возвращает массив с заголовками ответа сервера:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] => Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:14 GMT
    [Server] => Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
    [Last-Modified] => Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
    [ETag] => "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Content-Length] => 438
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Type] => text/html
)
```

[Информация в документации PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php)